# When $A\in M_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field $A^n=0$ if $A^k=0$ for some integer $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Why when $A\in M_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field then $A^n=0$ if $A^k=0$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Could you please elaborate how the linked question is related to the question here? I cannot see that.

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides $x^k$ and has degree less than $n$ @SeverinSchraven

Comment: Well, yes, I am just stupid. Sorry for that @TrevorGunn

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784631/a-is-a-complex-n-times-n-matrix-with-an-neq-0-then-ak-neq-0-foral

Comment: Also Marc's answer to the minimal polynomial question addresses this question directly.