# Let $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be linear transformation. Show that there are $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T^2+aT+bI=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a problem from the book Linear Algebra by Larry Smith and the author has so far introduced Vector Spaces. This problem shows up in the introductory chapter of Linear Transformations.

---

> Let $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be linear transformation.
>   Show that there are $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T^2+aT+bI=0$.

---

I think I have worked out the proof but I was looking for a simpler way. Here's how I did it:

I defined $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(x,y)=(t_1 (x,y) , t_2 (x,y))$ where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I showed that $T$ is a linear transformation iff $t_1$ and $t_2$ are linear transformations. Since every linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $ax+by$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, I completed it by comparing the components.

Is there any **far far** better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you know that every linear transformation has an associated matrix in the standard basis? Or have you not been taught this? If not, then the method you suggest is pretty much the only one available for use for the amount you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick any nonzero vector $v$. Then either $Tv$ is linearly independent of $v$, or $Tv=pv$ for some scalar $p$.

If $Tv$ is linearly independent of $v$, then $\{Tv,v\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Therefore $T^2v$ is a linear combination of $Tv$ and $v$ and $T^2v+aTv+bv=0$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. It follows that both $(T^2+aT+bI)v$ and $(T^2+aT+bI)(Tv)=T(T^2+aT+bI)v$ are zero. That is, $T^2+aT+bI$ maps a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ to zero. Hence $T^2+aT+bI$ must be zero.

If $Tv=pv$, then $(T-pI)v=0$. Let $u$ be any vector that is linearly independent of $v$. Then $\{u,v\}$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Hence $Tu$ is a linear combination of $u$ and $v$ and $Tu=qu+rv$ for some scalars $q$ and $r$. It follows that both $(T-pI)(T-qI)u=(T-pI)(rv)$ and $(T-pI)(T-qI)v=(T-qI)\left((T-pI)v\right)$ are zero. That is, $(T-pI)(T-qI)$ maps a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ to zero. Hence $(T-pI)(T-qI)$ must be zero. Expand the product, we get $T^2+aT+bI=0$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$.

*Edit.* If you are comfortable with the concept of minimal polynomial, a better proof is to show that the minimal polynomial of a linear operator $T$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space is at most of degree $n$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2298458) for instance.

Comment: Very well done indeed.  I was groping for such a proof but it eluded me, so I was forced to resort to the more mundane and less illuminating argument presented in my answer.  ***Endorsed, +1!!!***

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(\lambda) = \det(T-\lambda I)$ be the characteristic polynomial of T.  Then $f(T)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been following Larry Smith's Linear Algebra and I am yet to read Characteristic polynomials. Could this be achieved by  something else?

Comment: The brute force method that you used works, as you've seen.

Comment: It's kind of a wink-wink-nudge-nudge approach, but you could try showing that $a = -\operatorname{tr} T$ and $b = \det T$ satisfy the requirements. If you haven't covered either of these yet, you can just define them directly in terms of the standard matrix.

Answer (score 3):

With a "wink-wink-nudge-nudge" to Theo Bendit, respecting his comment on Robert Shore's answer, follows what is basically a variant of the "brute force" method, but one which illustrates the importance of the trace and determinant:

$\Bbb R^2$ is possessed of the *standard basis* $(1, 0)^T$, $(0, 1)^T$; in this basis we may represent $T$ by a matrix

$T = \begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} &  t_{22} \end{bmatrix}; \tag 1$

then

$T^2 = \begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} &  t_{22} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} &  t_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  t_{11}^2 + t_{12}t_{21} & t_{11}t_{12} + t_{12}t_{22} \\ t_{21}t_{11} + t_{22}t_{21} & t_{12}t_{21} + t_{22}^2 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

we "define" the two real numbers

$\det (T) = t_{11} t_{22} - t_{12}t_{21}; \tag 3$

$\text{Tr}(T) = t_{11} + t_{22}; \tag 4$

then

$T^2 + (\det (T)) I = \begin{bmatrix}  t_{11}^2 + t_{11}t_{22} & t_{11}t_{12} + t_{12}t_{22} \\ t_{21}t_{11} + t_{22}t_{21} & t_{11}t_{22} + t_{22}^2 \end{bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix}  t_{11}(t_{11} + t_{22}) & t_{12}(t_{11} + t_{22}) \\ t_{21}(t_{11} + t_{22}) & t_{22}(t_{11} + t_{22}) \end{bmatrix} = (\text{Tr}(T)) T, \tag 5$

whence
$T^2 - (\text{Tr}(T))T + (\det (T)) I = 0. \tag 6$

Comment: Say no more!$\hspace{0pt}$