Intuition behind degree of minimal polynomial
I'm learning linear algebra from Linear Algebra Done Right. The book gives a proof that the degree of the minimal polynomial of an operator on V is at most the dimension of V, but the proof feels unintuitive and doesn't really help me develop intuition for why this is true or what the minimal polynomial is beyond the definition. Is there a more intuitive way to explain it without using terms I haven't learned yet such as characteristic polynomials?
You can see the proof given by the book on this link on page 144.

Hi! Can you elaborate on what approach the proof from the book uses (broadly), and what kind of intuition you're looking for?

I am not sure if this helps, but I am going to quote page 147 where he give some intuition
"A nonzero polynomial has at most as many distinct zeros as its degree (see 4.8).
Thus (a) of the previous result, along with the result that the minimal polynomial
of an operator on  has degree at most dim , gives an alternative proof of 5.12,
which states that an operator on  has at most dim  distinct eigenvalues"

Personally when I read this section of the book years ago, I also found it a bit awkward. This stuff doesn't really click for you until you get your hands on a real Algebra book and learn about rings, fields, and etc.

@BrianTung You can see the proof on this link on page 144
https://linear.axler.net/LADR4e.pdf
The proof uses induction on dim V. It fixes a vector and constructs a monic polynimal of T that sends this vector to zero. Then it uses this polynomial to construct the minimal polynomial of T.
This proof feels a bit complicated and it's really hard for me to visualize it in my head. With all the previous linear algebra theorems in the book, I've been able to find a simple intuitive explanation.

@IAmNoOne This helps a bit but it's still hard for me to understand it intuitively. I'll have to think more about this angle. Do you recommend studying abstract algebra first and then continuing with linear algebra? I've been considering studying abstract algebra first anyway and if it will help me understand linear algebra it sounds to me like a better approach. I don't really care about motivating abstract algebra, I just want to methodically and thoroughly understand what I'm learning.

Tell you what:  please find the minimal polynomial for $$ = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 1 & 0 \
0 & 3 & 0 \
0 & 0 & 3 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

@WillJagy I think that it's x^2 - 6x + 9

I guess this is my advice:  find examples of square matrices with integer entries, up to size five, say, where you are assured that the eigenvalues are also integers.  For each such matrix $M $ construct a matrix $P$  of integers  such that $P^{-1} M P = J$ is in Jordan form.  The inverse of $P$ will usually have rational entries...  Let me find some

@erdonio The top answer from this post explains Axler's proof in different language, in case that helps with understanding at all: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298392/showing-that-the-minimal-polynomial-of-an-n-times-n-matrix-has-degree-at-most.

The matrix $P$ is often ignored, but it is crucial in the applications, differential equation systems or linear recurrences   $$ M = \left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \
-4 & 1 & -3 & 2 & 1 \
-2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \
-3 & -1 & -3 & 4 & 1 \
-8 & -2 & -7 & 5 & 4 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

@WillJagy I haven't learned Jordan form yet, it's taught much later in the book. But maybe I'll try learning it from another book so I can follow your advice. I was hoping to learn things in the order they are taught in the book I'm following but I'm really starting to have doubts about this book despite it being so highly regarded. Other explanations of the minimal polynomial I've seen online use Jordan form or characteristic polynomials, maybe this book doesn't teach it in the right order.

It may or may not be the right book for you. Meanwhile, the cure for lack of understanding is to do lots of examples. I have posted plenty of answers  of the type I'd indicated, all integer Jordan Form. My take on high school "algebra" is that it encapsulates out experience with numbers; for linear algebra, our experience with matrices, and such experience can precede the theory.  Let me find some posts

I put some links in an answer box

@erdonio Axler's book is predicated on the notion that proofs using determinants obfuscate deeper facts which may be revealed through other appropriate methods. One disadvantage of this choice is that the characteristic polynomial, which is typically defined using a determinant, is not introduced until much later in the book. It might be worth reading from another text about determinants and the characteristic polynomial.

Jordan form
Jordan decomposition - help with calculation of transformationmatrices?
Relation between left and right Jordan forms
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646324/if-matrix-a-beginbmatrix100-101-010-endbmatrix-then-a50/2646408#2646408
When is the following matrix diagonalizable?
Similarity of $3\times3$ matrices via Jordan canonical form
Solutions for a 3x3 ODE system with one eigenvalues (m=3).
What is the mistake in my matrix power formula?
Eigenvectors calculation: a defective matrix, a zero matrix
Ununderstanded Jordan normal form
Problem with generalized eigenvectors in a 3x3 matrix.
What is the minimal polynomial of A?  good one
Jordan basis unique?  vary generalized!
Finding Jordan-normal form of a special $n\times n$ matrix
how to define a function over a Jordanizable matrix
What values of $a$ make matrix $A$ diagonalisable?
Finding nilpotent and diagonalizable operators for a linear transformation $T$ (Jordan-Chevalley)
Matrix in canonical form of an orthogonal transformation  Real J form
Diagonalize matrix with complex eigenvalues by real basis Real J form
Jordan normal form (Basis)  ker W^3 \ ker W^2
Determine size or number of jordan blocks  ker W^3 \ ker W^2
Is this a correct basis for the Jordan normal form?

In a general vector space with dimension n you can’t have more than n independent vectors. This is because, in an n-dimensional space, any set of more than n vectors must be linearly dependent. Now consider a linear operator O acting on V. If you apply O repeatedly to V, you generate a sequence of vectors. Since V has dimension n, after n applications these vectors will become linearly dependent which implies that there is a polynomial of degrees at most n that O satisfies.

This is not correct. You only get that $p(A) v = 0$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree $\le n$, which doesn't imply that $p(A) = 0$. This can be turned into a complete proof but it requires some more work.

Thank you for the clarification. You are correct that the argument I provided shows that for each vector v in V, there exists a polynomial p(x) of degree at most n such that p (T)v =0. However, to conclude that p(T)=0 as an operator on the entire space V, we need to consider that this polynomial can be constructed for any vector in V. Since V is finite-dimensional, we can find a common min polynomial that works for all vectors in V and still has degree at most n. This common polynomial is the min polynomial of the operator. Thank you for pointing out the need to make this distinction clear.

@KurtMcKenzie Your assertion that $V$ being finite dimensional implies that there exists a common polynomial which works for all $v$ is essentially the statement of the theorem, so you still haven't provided a proof.

Thank you, Max! For each vector v in V, there is a polynomial p(x) of degree at most n such that p(T)v =0. Although these p(x)’s might be different for different vectors, since V is finite dimensional the set of all these polynomials forms an ideal in the ring of polynomials. The fact that this Ideal is generated by a single polynomial means there exist one polynomial that works for V. This is what we call the minimal polynomial and it has degree at most n, because it must divide any p(x). So the reason there is a common p(x) isn't just that the space is finite-dimensional.

@KurtMcKenzie Could you elaborate a bit more on this? I could be misunderstanding, but I think your current statement is a bit incorrect. If we let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\0&1&1\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$and take $v=(1,0,0)$, then the polynomial $p(x)=x-1$ works to annihilate $v$, yet the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)^2$. So I'm not sure how it's the case that the minimal polynomial divides all such $p$. I'd be interested in if there is a way to get around this, though.

Thx, Max, for the example. This is a valid point!  The polynomial p(x) = x-1 annihilates v, but the minimal polynomial for the entire matrix A is ( x - 1)^2, showing that while individual vectors can have annihilating polynomials of lower degree, the minimal polynomial is the smallest polynomial that works for V. So the minimal polynomial must divide any polynomial that annihilated the operator on the entire space but this doesn't mean that every annihilating polynomial for individual vectors is divisible by the minimal polynomial.

@KurtMcKenzie Right, that's kind of my point. Because no individual vector gives you a polynomial which we know the minimal polynomial must divide, I don't see how this method proves that the minimal polynomial has degree $\leq n$ without actually exhibiting some polynomial where $p(A)=0$.
